# Неправильное отображение текста при перемещении

Tags: c#, unity3d, ui

Проблема в отрисовки текста, верхней половине нормально но как перемещаю объект ниже текст становится по зади, и текст я уже в перёд немного двигал и слои менял, но проблема остаётся,
я новичок и многого не знаю.
[image: До перемещения]

[image: После перемещения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если объект является UI: В иерархии(Hierarchy) переместите текст выше объекта.

Если объект НЕ является UI: В Canvas установите sorting layer(Его сначала нужно создать и поставить выше default), либо просто поменяйте Order in layer на число выше